# How to stop JTextFields from running off the Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, layout-manager

I want to stop the text field from running off the GUI or print the text field on a new "line".

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private JTextField TextField0;
    private JTextField TextField1;
    private JCheckBox CheckBox0;
    private JPanel panel;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Window() {
        super("Checkbox");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        TextField0 = new JTextField("Add field",15);
        panel.add(TextField0);
        TextField1 = new JTextField("Add field", 15);

        CheckBox0 = new JCheckBox("");

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        TextField0.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if(event.getSource()==TextField0) {
                CheckBox0.setText(String.format("%s",event.getActionCommand()));
                panel.remove(TextField0);
                panel.add(CheckBox0);
                panel.add(TextField1);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable names should not start with upper case characters!!!

Answer (score 2):

There's not really anything you can do...

`JTextField` will allow the text to overflow the viewable area of the textfield (trimming the text on the screen)

You could try using a [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), which supports multi line text

You could also try packing the frame

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                String text = "This is a long piece of text that seems to go on and on and on and on an on....and some more...";

                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(10, 2);
                JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea(10, 2);

                field.setText(text);
                ta1.setText(text);
                ta2.setText(text);

                configure(ta1);
                configure(ta2);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                frame.add(field, gbc);
                frame.add(ta1, gbc);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta2), gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

            protected void configure(JTextArea ta) {
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
            }

        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout of your panel to a Boxlayout instead of a Borderlayout.  See the following link for the different layouts and how to use them:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between BorderLayout or BoxLayout for a single component

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you getting at